# update multiple rows in another table

Tags: mysql, sql

i need update table A, but result get from Table B.
below is my table result

TABLE A
FundCode  YTD
ABC       123.456

TABLE B
FundCode   YTD
ABC.UU     234.777

remarks :
FundCode from table B need to remove character after dot.

```
 UPDATE table A  
        SET YTD =t2.YTD
        from  table B t2
            WHERE t2.FundCode = t1.FundCode
```

i don't know how to only get substring in front

i need the result is 
TABLE A
FundCode  YTD
ABC       234.777

Answer (score 1):

You can use `join` in `update` statement

```
UPDATE a
JOIN b ON SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(b.FundCode, '.', 1), '.', -1) = a.FundCode
SET a.YTD=b.YTD;
```

Comment: i get error Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'join'.